# Prove: If function is defined and continuous on [a,b] ...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ is defined and continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f$ has no less than two values in its range, then set of points at which $f$ takes the minimum and maximum values can not be open.

---

PS It's quite obvious if draw a graph of the function. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Since $[a,b]$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, then $f([a,b])\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compact, but $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, then $f([a,b])$ is closed, and the maximum and minimum are attained in this set, thus your result follows.

Comment: I still don't get why the hypothesis that it has no less than 2 values...This is still true for constant function.

Comment: @Gina no it isn't. For constants the image set is a point, $y$, but then $f^{-1}(y)=[a,b]$ which **is** open in the topology on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @AdamHughes: And ALSO close on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yes, but the question doesn't say "not closed" it says "not open."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, the image, $f([a,b])\subseteq\Bbb R$ is a compact interval $[m,M]$ (compact because the domain is, connected by the intermediate value theorem). Assume that $x_n$ is a convergent sequence of points on the set $U$ where $f$ takes it's max value, $M$, then by continuity

$$f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=M$$

Hence $x=\lim x_n\in U$ and $U$ is closed. Similarly for the minimum value set, $V$, and the set of both is a finite union of closed sets, hence closed. The only closed set in $[a,b]$ which is also open in $[a,b]$ is the whole space, but then we've seen that $f$ takes on infinitely many values by the intermediate value theorem, hence $U\cup V\ne [a,b]$ (it is just the set where $f$ takes on max and min values which are just two of the infinitely many) hence it is not open.

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove that all level set of $f$ are closed. Therefore for every $y \in f([a,b])$ consider 
$$F_y := \{x \in [a,b]: f(x) = y\}.$$
We must have $F_y \neq \emptyset$ by definition of $y \in f([a,b])$. Now let $(x_n) \subset F_y$ be any converging sequence and denote by $\bar x$ its limit, then $f(x_n)=y$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and by continuity of $f$ we get
$$ y = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = f(\bar x).$$
This shows that $\bar x \in F_y$, thus $F_y$ is closed. Now if $m = \min_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ and $M = \min_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ it is clear that $F_m \cup F_M$ is closed as a finite union of closed sets.

Comment: I don't think the existence of the maximum and minimum was in the question.

Comment: @egreg I let it as a complement of proof.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question either.

Comment: @egreg Right... I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Preimage of a close set is close for continuous function. A set of just 1 point is close. Hence for any $y$ (whether $y$ is the maximum value or not), we have $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a close set in the domain $[a,b]$. A close set of a close subspace is still close, hence $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is also close in $\mathbb{R}$.

When $y$ is maximum and minimum, this set is non-empty since maximum and minimum exist ($f$ is a continuous function on a compact interval). Since $f$ have at least 2 value, $f^{-1}(\{y\})\not=[a,b]$. Since $[a,b]$ is connected (and so does $\mathbb{R}$), and since $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is close, it is not open in neither $[a,b]$ nor $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $f$ take on 2 values, it must take 3 values, by intermediate value theorem. Hence if we let $A$ be the set of both the maximum and minimum value, then $f^{-1}(A)\not=[a,b]$ and is still close (since $A$ is close). Hence just as above, it is not open.

Comment: Closed sets can also be open, and $f^{-1}(A)$ is a subset of $[a,b]$, not of $\Bbb R$, so there are some closed sets which are also open there, but which would not be open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AdamHughes: the asker is trying to prove that the set is CLOSE. At no point is it relevant to ask whether $f^{-1}(y)$ is open or not. Yes there are open set in $[a,b]$ that are not open in $\mathbb{R}$, but that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: if you read the original question you'll see the op asks to show the set is "not open," but it does not say "closed." Closed is not the same as "not open."

Comment: @AdamHughes:I swear I must have misread that as close. Guess I need to fix this.

Comment: No worries, I figured it was something like that; I just didn't want you to get downvoted for misreading the question. :-)

Comment: Also, this is still not quite complete:  the function could ostensibly take on two values:  $m$ and $M$, which are the max and min, the inverse image could then be $f^{-1}(\{m,M\})$ which is **two** values, so it could (a priori) be the entire space, so you need to address that as well.

Comment: @AdamHughes: thanks a lot, I got that fixed. Now that explains why it sounds like there are unnecessary hypothesis when I first read it.

Comment: @AdamHughes: I guessed I interpreted the question to mean the set for each value, not both. Well I can add something to this too.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the set 'E' is open and x is in $E_x$ (the component of x in E). Then there is a ball $(x-r,x+r)$ in $E_x$. let $x'$ in $E_x$. If $x,x'$ are both  min/max. then f takes every value in-between $f(x), f(x')$,EDIT re Adam's comment is  possible, since every value in $E_x$ is an extreme value. Then x' is a max and x is a min. Again, f takes every value in-between $f(x),f(x')$. But tjis is not possible either. Then f must be constant in each component, say $f (E_x)=c_x$. But, since {$c_x$} is closed, so {$f^{-1}(c_x)$} is also closed, so E is not the disjoint union of open intervals, and then E is not open EDIT unless (by connectedness of [a,b]) $E=[a,b]$. But this is not possible, since f is not constant(" f takes at least two values". )

Comment: Why is that a problem? You just have that the max/min is not a single point, it can be that a function like

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & 0\le x\le 1 \\ 1 & 1\le x\le 2\end{cases}$$

Which has a lot of maxes in a neighborhood of an extreme value, such as $(1.25, 1.75)$.

Comment: o.k , let me show f cannot be of that form.

Comment: Your conclusion still doesn't follow from your argument. You **can** conclude that $x,x'$ are both the **same** kind of extreme value on the interval $(x-r,x+r)$, but not that one is one kind and the other is another kind.

Comment: I tried (and thin I did) show both extremes must be of the same type, i.e., E_x is locally-constant; that is (one o the things) I tried to show, tho this does not give a proof, I am trying to extend it into a proof .

Comment: You really want to use connectedness somewhere, it's false for $[a,b]\cup [c,d]$ when $a<b<c<d$ since we can use:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\in [a,b] \\ 2 & x\in [c,d]\end{cases}$$

Comment: Well yes, but [a,b] is connected, so I don't think that will be an issue.

Comment: It won't, but if you don't use the connectedness in your proof there is an error, since that condition is *necessary* to ensure the conclusion follows. (without it, there is a counterexample)

Comment: I completed the edit; thanks for input.

Comment: The topology on $[a,b]$ allows for a closed and open subset, namely $[a,b]$ itself, which is not a disjoint union of open intervals.

Comment: Maybe then we go back to connectedness: only clopen sets are $\emptyset$ and $[a,b]$. But $f \neq c$ , so $[a,b]$ not possible.

Comment: Indeed, but then you need to argue that neither can happen. Both are simple:  $[a,b]$ by the intermediate value theoremç not just because $f\ne c$, since you use continuity as well, and $\varnothing$ because there **is** some max.